# Prepping to update a Core ML Model

Tags: swift, machine-learning, coreml

Core ML 3 now gives us the ability to perform on-device training. After creating an updatable Core ML Model, we need to perform some function to update it on-device by using the `MLUpdateTask` function which requires 3 parameters: `Model URL`, `MLBatchProvider` and `MLModelConfiguration`.

Since Core ML 3 was just released, documentation for it is very limited; specifically on how to prepare the training data or an `MLBatchProvider`

Question: How do you prepare training data or create an `MLBatchprovider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Model is Named `TestModel` a `TestModelTrainingInput` class should be available.

```swift
let singleTrainingData = try TestModelTrainingInput(input: .init[1,2,3], output_true: .init([4,5,6]))
let trainingData = MLArrayBatchProvider(array: [singleTrainingData])
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! And I'm assuming the training input parameters would depend on the type of model it is, right?

Comment: Yes, in my case a 3D input and outputvector

Comment: As I understood, in order to have *TrainingInput class available, model first needs to be updatable. Which is not by default? And can be achieved with coremltools?

Answer (score 0):

To provide data to Core ML, you create an `MLFeatureProvider` object. This returns one or more `MLFeatureValue` objects, one for each input in your model. Normally the auto-generated class does this behind the scenes.

If you want to work with a batch, you create an `MLBatchProvider` that has multiple `MLFeatureProviders`, one for each example.

Making an `MLBatchProvider` for predictions isn't so hard: just put your `MLFeatureProviders` in an array and then use `MLArrayBatchProvider`. Again, the auto-generated class has a helper method for this.

For training you probably want to load the data on-the-fly, do random augmentations, and so on. In that case, you'll want to make a new class that adopts the `MLBatchProvider` protocol. It should return an `MLFeatureProvider` for each example. This time the `MLFeatureProvider` does not just have the `MLFeatureValue` for the example but also an `MLFeatureValue` for the target / true label. (The auto-generated class has a helper class for this training feature provider, but not for the training batch provider.)

I haven't actually gotten any of the new training APIs to work yet (they crash on beta 2), so I'm not 100% sure yet how the `MLBatchProvider` would cycle through an entire epoch of training examples.

Comment: Would it be possible to show some sudo code on how this would look like?

Comment: Which part? (I don't know yet how to do it for training.)